# How to install ChessX in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, chess

I tried to install ChessX using Ubuntu Software Center.
But it shows error.
Hence,How to install it? 
Or Any alternate Chess Game for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: What is the error ? Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install chessx` add any errors to the question, FYI it installed fine in terminal, for me, on 14.04 and it runs too

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install Xboard`.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chessx : Depends: libqt4-core but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libqt4-gui but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get -f install && apt-get update`, then try `sudo apt-get install chessx`, did it work ?

Comment: You already did it, the big green tick next to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here, based on your terminal output is:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

To fix this, open terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get -f install && apt-get update
```

Then try the install again

```
sudo apt-get install chessx
```

Comment: Yes, the package was broken, But using your method, i got it @mark kirby

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that [Universe Repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) are enabled.

Once that is done, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install chessx
```

Comment: how to know  whether universe repositories are enabled?

Comment: Click on the link in the answer, and it will show you how to check.

Comment: It is in Enabled mode only @Mitch

Comment: If its enabled, just install chessx.  I just tried it, and it works.

Comment: yeah it worked for me too  by using this, i got it, sudo apt-get -f install && apt-get update, then i tried sudo apt-get install chessx @mitch